# "it's time for" "it's time to"

Tags: translation

How would one say the phrases "it's time for bed" or "it's time to eat" in Esperanto?

Certainly "estas tempo por" wouldn't work as that sounds more like "there is a time for," so what would be the correct way to say this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *estas tempo* means that. *Esti* means *to be* and *there to be* (and other things).

Example (mine):

> Infanoj! Bonvolu liberigi la tablon, estas tempo manĝi

From Zamenhof (Tekstaro):

> Adiaŭ! Estas tempo disiri.